# Why can't I get both class when I run my program in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I am trying to run my program with both classes used. However when I run my program it does't allow me to select my Player class (as you can see in the image below). How do I fix this?
Thank you for your time and help!

[image]

Comment: Does your `Player` class have a main method entry point?

Answer (score 1):

All is good and working with Eclipse; it looks as it should. The Save and Launch dialogue simply means that you've already saved your player class, so there's no need to "re-save" it. Your Main class has been modified, and therefore needs to be "re-saved". However, if you've checked this, make sure that you have an instance of your Player class in your Main class! If you're unsure what this means, look at the code below:

```
Player player = new Player();


private Player player;
player = new Player();


Player player;
player = new Player();
```

If you've done that, but the code *still* isn't working, make sure you're calling the method createPlayer() from your instance.

If you've made sure you have that in it, I really can't find where the problem is.